# QAction cannot be checked

Tags: python, pyqt, qmenu

I am 'converting' my (nested menus) QMenu object into a QAction (using `setMenu`) so that I can toggle checkboxes on them but the checkbox are unable to be toggled, it just remains as checked.

```py
import functools
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class QSubAction(QtGui.QAction):
    def __init__(self, text="", parent=None):
        super(QSubAction, self).__init__(text, parent)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setChecked(True)

class QAddAction(QtGui.QAction):
    def __init__(self, icon=None, text="Add Item", parent=None):
        if icon:
            super(QAddAction, self).__init__(icon, text, parent)
        else:
            super(QAddAction, self).__init__(text, parent)

class QCustomMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    """Customized QMenu."""

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super(QCustomMenu, self).__init__(title=str(title), parent=parent)
        self.setup_menu()

    def setup_menu(self):
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        no_right_click = [QAddAction]
        if any([isinstance(self.actionAt(event.pos()), instance) for instance in no_right_click]):
            return
        pos = event.pos()

    def addAction(self, action):
        super(QCustomMenu, self).addAction(action)

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):         
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Context menu')    

        self.qmenu = QCustomMenu(title='', parent=self)
        add_item_action = QtGui.QAction('Add Main item', self,
            triggered=self.add_new_item)
        self.qmenu.addAction(add_item_action)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        action = self.qmenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

    def add_new_item(self):
        main_menu_name, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(
            self,
            'Main Menu',
            'Name of new Menu Item:'
        )
        if ok:
            self._addMenuItemTest(main_menu_name)

    def _addMenuItemTest(self, main_menu_name):
        icon_path = '/user_data/add.png'

        base_qmenu = QCustomMenu(title=main_menu_name, parent=self)
        base_qmenu.setTearOffEnabled(True)                     

        add_item_action = QAddAction(None, 'Add Sub Item', base_qmenu)
        slot = functools.partial(self.add_sub_item, base_qmenu)
        add_item_action.triggered.connect(slot)
        base_qmenu.addAction(add_item_action)
        # self.qmenu.addMenu(base_qmenu)

        test_action = QtGui.QAction(main_menu_name, self)
        test_action.setMenu(base_qmenu)
        test_action.setCheckable(True)
        test_action.setChecked(True)
        self.qmenu.addAction(test_action)



    def add_sub_item(self, base_menu):
        sub_menu_name, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(
            self,
            'Sub Menu',
            'Name of new Sub Item:'
        )
        if ok:
            action = QSubAction(sub_menu_name, self)
            slot = functools.partial(
                self._callActionItem,
                str(base_menu.title()),
                str(sub_menu_name)
            )
            action.setCheckable(True)
            action.setChecked(True)
            action.toggled.connect(slot)
            base_menu.addAction(action)

    def _callActionItem(self, title, menu):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Example()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use `PySide`.
I tried to solve this question by using `PySide`.

As the result, please look this code and execute it.

```
import functools
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class QSubAction(QtGui.QAction):
    def __init__(self, text="", parent=None):
        super(QSubAction, self).__init__(text, parent)
        self.setCheckable(True)
        self.setChecked(True)

class QAddAction(QtGui.QAction):
    def __init__(self, icon=None, text="Add Item", parent=None):
        if icon:
            super(QAddAction, self).__init__(icon, text, parent)
        else:
            super(QAddAction, self).__init__(text, parent)

class QCustomMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    """Customized QMenu."""

    def __init__(self, title, parent=None):
        super(QCustomMenu, self).__init__(title=str(title), parent=parent)
        self.setup_menu()
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        action = self.activeAction()
        if isinstance(action,QtGui.QAction):
            action.trigger()
        return QtGui.QMenu.mousePressEvent(self,event)
    def setup_menu(self):
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        no_right_click = [QAddAction]
        if any([isinstance(self.actionAt(event.pos()), instance) for instance in no_right_click]):
            return
        pos = event.pos()

    def addAction(self, action):
        super(QCustomMenu, self).addAction(action)

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Example, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):         
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Context menu')    

        self.qmenu = QCustomMenu(title='', parent=self)
        add_item_action = QtGui.QAction('Add Main item', self,
            triggered=self.add_new_item)
        self.qmenu.addAction(add_item_action)

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        action = self.qmenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

    def add_new_item(self):
        main_menu_name, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(
            self,
            'Main Menu',
            'Name of new Menu Item:'
        )
        if ok:
            self._addMenuItemTest(main_menu_name)

    def _addMenuItemTest(self, main_menu_name):
        icon_path = '/user_data/add.png'

        base_qmenu = QCustomMenu(title=main_menu_name, parent=self)
        base_qmenu.setTearOffEnabled(True)                     

        add_item_action = QAddAction(None, 'Add Sub Item', base_qmenu)
        slot = functools.partial(self.add_sub_item, base_qmenu)
        add_item_action.triggered.connect(slot)
        base_qmenu.addAction(add_item_action)
        # self.qmenu.addMenu(base_qmenu)

        test_action = QtGui.QAction(main_menu_name, self)
        test_action.setMenu(base_qmenu)
        test_action.setCheckable(True)
        test_action.setChecked(True)
        self.connect(test_action,QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered(bool)"),self.unsetCheck_action)


        self.qmenu.addAction(test_action)

    def unsetCheck_action(self,checked):

        sender_obj = self.sender()
        if isinstance(sender_obj,QtGui.QAction): 


            sender_obj.setChecked(checked)




    def add_sub_item(self, base_menu):
        sub_menu_name, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(
            self,
            'Sub Menu',
            'Name of new Sub Item:'
        )
        if ok:
            action = QSubAction(sub_menu_name, self)
            slot = functools.partial(
                self._callActionItem,
                str(base_menu.title()),
                str(sub_menu_name)
            )
            action.setCheckable(True)
            action.setChecked(True)
            action.toggled.connect(slot)
            base_menu.addAction(action)

    def _callActionItem(self, title, menu):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Example()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The points of change.

1.CustomMenu has MousePressEvent.

```
def mousePressEvent(self,event):
    action = self.activeAction()
    if isinstance(action,QtGui.QAction):
        action.trigger()
    return QtGui.QMenu.mousePressEvent(self,event)
```

If you click the action on the menu,you get the action.
And you call `action.trigger()`
And you can connect `action.triggered` Signal.
yes,"triggered" is after "triggering".

2.**to connect trigger.**

```
self.connect(test_action,QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered(bool)"),self.unsetCheck_action)
def unsetCheck_action(self,checked):

        sender_obj = self.sender()
        if isinstance(sender_obj,QtGui.QAction): 


            sender_obj.setChecked(checked)
```

As you can see,if the test action is triggered,the triggered signal is called.
And the slot is `unsetCheck_action` method.

for changing the action chack,you can manipulate only it seems that the trigger and not need to switch between True and False.

**faled in PySide**

In PyQt, it may be better to connect by `test_action.triggered[bool].connect()`
But I could not do it by `PySide`.

I don't have `PyQt4` in my machine. if you have some problems, please don't hesitate to ask me further information.

Comment: many thanks for your reply. While I am able to use your code, it seems to have broken the toggling for the `sub` item (it is set to checked all the time, even when it is in a tear-off window, it seems to work but it is not). I tried to implement the same logic you have done for the `main` item into the `sub` item but I am unable to get much results

Comment: As you said,certainly, an error happened.`TypeError: _callActionItem() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`.But this error has also occured in your code.That is to say,it was originally coded.If you want to solve this error,I recommend that you put a new question for solving it,because this question focuses on the switching of `QAction` by triggering them.So I answered only this point.thanks.Or, do you have another problem?

Comment: Noted, created [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485535/qaction-toggling-is-hinder-by-qmenu-mousepressevent) for it. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry,`if isinstance(action,QtGui.QAction)` is not needed,because it is very clear that the return is `QAction`.